# Create a custom logging handler for WildFly

Tags: java, logging, wildfly-11

Does anyone knows how to create a custom handler and set the properties for a logging handler inside Wildfly 11? There is some official documentation, but most of the time is not up to date, some answers are missleading, incomplete or pointing to nowhere and some are old / deprecated. I have to create a custom handler and intercept the log record before sending it to the writer. Maybe a custom Filter should be added to this handler, since it might be the case that the record to be a candidate for not writing it to the server.log

Comment: So you want to get to the message before it's written to the server.log?

Comment: Yes, this is the solution that I want. Meanwhile, I found out that it can be achieved by extending the SizeRotatingFileHanlder.java class. If anyone interested, I can add some more info about